# How do you extract IP addresses from files using a regex in a linux shell?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, command-line

How to extract a text part by regexp in linux shell? Lets say, I have a file where in every line is an IP address, but on a different position. What is the simplest way to extract those IP addresses using common unix command-line tools?

Comment: You might try my suggestion posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389565/249079

Comment: grep -E -o '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' file.txt

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44654954/3832970) if you need to make sure you do not extract `128.0.0.1` from a string like `65465656768128.0.0.1233453`.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You could use [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) to pull them out.

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' file.txt
```

Comment: I had to remove slashes and it worked: `egrep -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' file`

Comment: grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' file.txt | sort | uniq for unique IP addresses.

Comment: making it a tad more clean: grep -o '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'

Comment: I am checking in late here but I was hoping for clarity on the answer. Why do you need to include backslashes within the curly brackets? I tried to use the answer given by the person who removed those backslashes but it doesn't work. I understand that the backslash allows you grep to read the periods as a literal, but I don't understand why you would read the curly brackets as a literal. Any clarification would be helpful.

Comment: You can pass a list of all .txt files to that snippet  with xargs like : `find | grep ".txt" | xargs grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'`

Answer (score 49):

Most of the examples here will match on 999.999.999.999 which is not technically a valid IP address.

The following will match on only valid IP addresses (including network and broadcast addresses).

```
grep -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' file.txt
```

Omit the -o if you want to see the entire line that matched.

Comment: This also matches on 1233.123.123.123

Comment: Technically it's matching 233.123.123.123 even though there is a 1 right before it. It doesn't restrict what can be before and after the IP address.

Comment: Is there a way to spit out the path,filename, and line number along with the matched IP?

Comment: If you add the -n argument it will print the line number as well. If you specify multiple files like *.txt then it will print the file name as well. If you use -r it will search subdirectories and print the full path of the file.

Comment: This does not match 127.0.0.1, the rule requires it to be written like 127.000.000.001, which is not the standard way to write it? Another example is 8.8.8.8 which needs to be written as 008.008.008.008. Why upvote this 36 times? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 23):

This works fine for me in access logs.

```
cat access_log | egrep -o '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

Let's break it part by part.

- `[0-9]{1,3}` means one to three occurrences of the range mentioned in []. In this case it is 0-9. so it matches patterns like 10 or 183.
- Followed by a '.'. We will need to escape this as '.' is a meta character and has special meaning for the shell.

So now we are at patterns like '123.' '12.' etc.

- This pattern repeats itself three times(with the '.'). So we enclose it in brackets.
  `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}`
- And lastly the pattern repeats itself but this time without the '.'. That is why we kept it separately in the 3rd step.  `[0-9]{1,3}`

If the ips are at the beginning of each line as in my case use:

```
egrep -o '^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

where '^' is an anchor that tells to search at the start of a line.

Comment: Prints invalid ip addresses.

Answer (score 11):

I usually start with grep, to get the regexp right.

```
# [multiple failed attempts here]
grep    '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*'                 file  # good?
grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' file  # good enough
```

Then I'd try and convert it to `sed` to filter out the rest of the line.  (After reading this thread, you and I aren't going to do that anymore: we're going to use `grep -o` instead)

```
sed -ne 's/.*\([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\).*/\1/p  # FAIL
```

That's when I usually get annoyed with `sed` for not using the same regexes as anyone else.  So I move to `perl`.

```
$ perl -nle '/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/ and print $&'
```

Perl's good to know in any case.  If you've got a teeny bit of CPAN installed, you can even make it more reliable at little cost:

```
$ perl -MRegexp::Common=net -nE '/$RE{net}{IPV4}/ and say $&' file(s)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html). But if you know perl, that might be easier, and more useful to know in the long run:

```
perl -n '/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print "$1\n"' < file
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a little [script](http://digitalcrunch.com/perl/extract-ipv4-address-from-text-using-perl/) to see my log files better, it's nothing special, but might help a lot of the people who are learning perl.   It does DNS lookups on the IP addresses after it extracts them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some shell helper I made:
https://github.com/philpraxis/ipextract

included them here for convenience:

```
#!/bin/sh
ipextract () 
{ 
egrep --only-matching -E  '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' 
}

ipextractnet ()
{ 
egrep --only-matching -E  '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/[[:digit:]]+' 
}

ipextracttcp ()
{ 
egrep --only-matching -E  '[[:digit:]]+/tcp' 
}

ipextractudp ()
{ 
egrep --only-matching -E  '[[:digit:]]+/udp' 
}

ipextractsctp ()
{ 
egrep --only-matching -E  '[[:digit:]]+/sctp' 
}

ipextractfqdn ()
{ 
egrep --only-matching -E  '[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}' 
}
```

Load it / source it (when stored in ipextract file) from shell:

> $ . ipextract

Use them:

```
$ ipextract < /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1
255.255.255.255
$
```

For some example of real use:

```
ipextractfqdn < /var/log/snort/alert | sort -u
dmesg | ipextractudp
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

Comment: This prints invalid ip addresses.

Answer (score 2):

For those who want a ready solution for getting IP addresses from apache log and listing occurences of how many times IP address has visited website, use this line:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' error.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > occurences.txt
```

Nice method to ban hackers. Next you can:

1. Delete lines with less than 20 visits
2. Using regexp cut till single space so you will have only IP addresses
3. Using regexp cut 1-3 last numbers of IP addresses so you will have only network addresses
4. Add `deny from` and a space at the beginning of each line
5. Put the result file as .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest perl. (\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+) should probably do the trick.

EDIT: Just to make it more like a complete program, you could do something like the following (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

while (<>) {
    if (/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

This handles one IP per line. If you have more than one IPs per line, you need to use the /g option. *man perlretut* gives you a more detailed tutorial on regular expressions.

Comment: You could always write that in one line and use perl -n or perl -e to execute it but IMHO a small script like this is easier to handle, especially if you want to keep it and modify it later for other patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk, as well. Something like ...

```
awk '{i=1; if (NF > 0) do {if ($i ~ /regexp/) print $i; i++;} while (i <= NF);}' file
```

May require cleaning. just a quick and dirty response to shows basically how to do it with awk.

Comment: still the one with grep looks most elegant and easy

Comment: Oh, agreed. Just thought it would be useful to show a variety of methods in case someone wanted to know, specifically, how to do it with awk.

Answer (score 0):

All of the previous answers have one or more problems. The accepted answer allows ip numbers like 999.999.999.999. The currently second most upvoted answer requires prefixing with 0 such as 127.000.000.001 or 008.008.008.008 instead of 127.0.0.1 or 8.8.8.8. Apama has it almost right, but that expression requires that the ipnumber is the only thing on the line, no leading or trailing space allowed, nor can it select ip's from the middle of a line.

I think the correct regex can be found on http://www.regextester.com/22

So if you want to extract all ip-adresses from a file use:

```
grep -Eo "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" file.txt
```

If you don't want duplicates use:

```
grep -Eo "(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" file.txt | sort | uniq
```

Please comment if there still are problems in this regex. It easy to find many wrong regex for this problem, I hope this one has no real issues.

Comment: I found that this expression selects "56.1.1.1" from input ip "256.1.1.1". I think that is correct. 256.1.1.1 is not a legal ip number, so the correct ip must be 56.1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here is using really long-handed regular expressions but actually understanding the regex of POSIX will allow you to use a small `grep` command like this for printing IP addresses.

```
grep -Eo "(([0-9]{1,3})\.){3}([0-9]{1,3})"
```

(Side note)
This doesn't ignore invalid IPs but it is very simple.

Comment: This also matches `...`

Comment: Seems to only happen for me when I specifically pipe `...` into the command. Adding `[0-9]` before the first parentheses seems to fix it. Added to the command. If you catch anymore bugs just let me know.

Comment: I think you want `"([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+"` (otherwise you'd still match, e.g., `0...`).

Comment: I have actually had a problem with that one. When I used it on a file I created with a for loop and `tr -dc '0-9.' </dev/urandom | head -c 16`, it would print all manner of wrong lines. However I think `(([0-9]{1,3})\.){3}([0-9]{1,3})` is getting close to a compact since it doesn't print incorrect lines such as `0...111230..24...`. However, it doesn't yet check if each octal is `0` or greater than `255`. Which I am working on now.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all answers but all of them had one or many problems that I list a few of them.

1. Some detected `123.456.789.111` as valid IP
2. Some don't detect `127.0.00.1` as valid IP
3. Some don't detect IP that start with zero like `08.8.8.8`

So here I post a regex that works on all above conditions.

> Note : I have extracted more than 2 millions IP without any problem with following regex.

```
(?:(?:1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d|0?[1-9]\d|0?0?\d)\.){3}(?:1\d\d|2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4]\d|0?[1-9]\d|0?0?\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an informative blog article about this topic: [How to Extract IPv4 and IPv6 IP Addresses from Plain Text Using Regex](https://codverter.com/blog/articles/tech/20190105-extract-ipv4-ipv6-ip-addresses-using-regex.html).

In the article there's a detailed guide of the most common different patterns for IPs, often required to be extracted and isolated from plain text using regular expressions.
This guide is based on CodVerter's [IP Extractor](https://codverter.com/src/ipextractor) source code tool for handling IP addresses extraction and detection when necessary.

If you wish to validate and capture IPv4 Address this pattern can do the job:

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.]){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

or to validate and capture IPv4 Address with **Prefix** ("slash notation"):

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.]){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?/[0-9]{1,2})\b
```

or to capture subnet mask or wildcard mask:

```
(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)[.](255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)[.](255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)[.](255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)
```

or to filter out subnet mask addresses you do it with regex [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\b((?!(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)[.](255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)[.](255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)[.](255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0)))(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.]){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

For **IPv6** validation you can go to the article link I have added at the top of this answer.
Here is an example for capturing all the common patterns (taken from CodVerter`s IP Extractor Help Sample):

[image]

If you wish you can test the IPv4 regex [here](https://codverter.com/src/regextester?query=b85ed836-4843-4ded-a1e6-3fdc21a8ac77).

Answer (score 0):

The *awk* example above didn't work for me, and I needed to do it with *awk* specifically, so I came up with this method:

```
$ awk '{match($0,/[0-9]{1,3}+\.[0-9]{1,3}+\.[0-9]{1,3}+\.[0-9]{1,3}+/); ip = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); print ip}' your_sample_file.log
```

You can also just use pipes if you're getting the data from somewhere else. Eg, *ipconfig*

I also realized the method matches invalid IP addresses.

Here is an extended version that only matches valid IPv4 Addresses:

```
$ awk 'match($0, /(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' sample_file.log
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It's a REALLY brute-force type of solution, and I haven't had time to handle things like subnet masks.

Since many `awk` variants lack backreferences in `regex`, range notation in regex `{n,m}`, `FPAT` ability, an array target for `match()`, I have to try my best to emulate some of that functionality here.

The `regex` itself is very basic, and it's very much intentional, since each of candidates that passed through the first layer filter will then be fed into the ip4 validation function to ensure values are in range.

Additionally, I use a second array to handle the duplicate scenario (although it's only de-duped in the ASCII string sense - leading zeros, for now, will show up multiple times for each unique ASCII string representation of it).

I know it's ultra brute-force and unseemly of a solution - there's only so much lemonade I can make out of the lemons I have.

```
 echo "${bbbbbbbb}" \
 \
  | mawk 'function validIP4(_,__,___) {
    
      __^=__=___=4;—-__
      if(--___!=gsub("[.]","_",_)) { 
          return !___ }
      ++___
      do {
          if ((+_<-_)||(__<+_)||(--___<-___)) {
             _="[|]"
             break 
      } } while (sub("^[^_]+[_]","",_))
      
      return _!="[|]" 

   } BEGIN {   FS = RS = "^$"
            __=(__= (__="[0]*([012]?[0-9])?[0-9][.]")__)__
       sub("...$","",__) 

   } END {
      
     gsub(/[^0-9.]+/,OFS)
     gsub(__,"=&~")
     gsub(/[~][^0-9.=~]+[=]/,"~=")

     gsub(/^[^=~]+[=~]|[=~][^=~]+$/,"")
     split($(_<_),___,"[=~]+")

     for(_ in ___) { 
         if ( ! (____[__=___[_]]++)) { 
         if (validIP4(__)) { 
               print (__)   } } } }' \
                                      \
  | gsort -t'.' -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n \
  | gcat -n              \
  | rs -t -c$'\n' -C= 0 4 \
  | column -s= -t \
  |  lgp3 5

     1  00.69.84.243        76  23.108.43.3        151  79.127.56.148       226 172.241.192.165
     2  00.71.110.228       77  23.108.43.19       152  80.48.119.28        227 172.245.220.154
     3  00.105.215.18       78  23.108.43.55       153  80.76.60.2          228 175.196.182.58
     4  00.123.2.171        79  23.108.43.94       154  80.244.229.102      229 176.74.9.62
     5  00.123.228.2        80  23.108.43.120      155  81.8.52.78          230 176.214.97.55

     6  00.201.223.164      81  23.108.43.208      156  83.166.241.233      231 177.128.44.131
     7  01.51.106.70        82  23.108.43.244      157  85.25.4.28          232 177.129.53.114
     8  01.144.14.232       83  23.108.75.98       158  85.25.91.156        233 178.88.185.2
     9  01.148.85.50        84  23.108.75.164      159  85.25.91.161        234 180.180.171.123
    10  01.174.10.170       85  23.225.64.59       160  85.25.117.171       235 180.183.15.198

    11  02.64.120.219       86  36.37.177.186      161  85.25.150.32        236 180.250.153.129
    12  02.68.128.214       87  36.94.161.219      162  85.25.201.22        237 181.36.230.242
    13  02.129.196.242      88  37.48.82.87        163  85.195.104.71       238 181.191.141.43
    14  02.134.127.15       89  37.144.180.52      164  85.208.211.163      239 182.253.186.140
    15  03.28.246.130       90  41.65.236.56       165  85.209.149.130      240 185.24.233.208

    16  03.73.194.2         91  41.65.251.86       166  88.119.195.35       241 185.61.152.137
    17  03.80.77.1          92  41.79.65.241       167  91.107.15.221       242 185.74.7.51
    18  03.81.77.194        93  41.161.92.138      168  91.188.246.246      243 185.93.205.236
    19  03.97.200.52        94  41.164.68.42       169  93.184.8.74         244 185.138.114.113
    20  3.120.173.144       95  41.164.68.194      170  94.16.15.100        245 186.3.85.131

    21  03.134.97.233       96  41.205.24.155      171  94.75.76.3          246 186.5.117.82
    22  03.148.72.192       97  43.255.113.232     172  94.228.204.229      247 186.46.168.42
    23  03.150.113.147      98  45.5.68.18         173  95.181.150.121      248 186.96.50.39
    24  03.159.46.18        99  45.5.68.25         174  95.181.151.105      249 186.154.211.106
    25  03.162.181.132     100  45.43.63.230       175  110.74.200.177      250 186.167.48.138

    26  03.177.45.7        101  45.67.212.99       176  112.163.123.242     251 186.202.176.153
    27  03.177.45.10       102  45.67.230.13       177  113.161.59.136      252 186.233.186.60
    28  03.177.45.11       103  45.71.203.110      178  115.87.196.88       253 186.251.71.193
    29  03.217.169.100     104  45.87.249.80       179  116.212.155.229     254 187.217.54.84
    30  03.232.215.194     105  45.122.233.76      180  117.54.114.101      255 188.94.225.177

    31  04.208.138.14      106  45.131.213.170     181  117.54.114.102      256 188.95.89.81
    32  04.244.75.205      107  45.158.158.29      182  117.54.114.103      257 188.133.153.143
    33  5.39.189.39        108  45.179.193.70      183  119.82.241.21       258 188.138.89.50
    34  05.149.219.201     109  45.183.142.126     184  120.72.20.225       259 188.138.90.226
    35  5.149.219.201      110  45.184.103.68      185  121.1.41.162        260 188.166.218.243

    36  5.189.229.42       111  45.184.155.7       186  123.31.30.100       261 190.128.225.115
    37  07.151.182.247     112  45.189.113.63      187  125.25.33.241       262 190.217.7.73
    38  07.154.221.245     113  45.189.117.237     188  125.25.206.28       263 190.217.19.243
    39  07.244.242.103     114  45.192.141.247     189  133.242.146.103     264 192.3.219.94
    40  08.177.248.47      115  45.229.32.190      190  137.74.93.21        265 192.99.38.64

    41  08.177.248.213     116  45.250.65.15       191  137.184.57.245      266 192.140.42.83
    42  08.177.248.217     117  46.99.146.232      192  139.5.151.182       267 192.155.107.59
    43  8.210.83.33        118  46.243.220.70      193  139.59.233.24       268 192.254.104.201
    44  8.213.128.19       119  46.246.80.6        194  139.255.58.212      269 194.5.193.183
    45  8.213.128.30       120  47.74.114.83       195  140.238.19.26       270 194.114.128.149

    46  8.213.128.41       121  47.88.79.154       196  151.106.13.221      271 194.233.67.98
    47  8.213.128.106      122  47.91.44.217       197  151.106.18.126      272 194.233.69.41
    48  8.213.128.123      123  47.243.75.115      198  152.26.229.67       273 194.233.73.103
    49  8.213.128.131      124  47.254.28.2        199  152.32.143.109      274 194.233.73.104
    50  8.213.128.149      125  49.156.47.162      200  153.122.106.94      275 194.233.73.105

    51  8.213.128.152      126  50.195.227.153     201  153.122.107.129     276 194.233.73.107
    52  8.213.128.158      127  50.235.149.74      202  154.85.35.235       277 194.233.73.109
    53  8.213.128.171      128  50.250.56.129      203  154.95.36.182       278 194.233.88.38
    54  8.213.128.172      129  51.68.199.120      204  154.236.162.59      279 195.80.49.3
    55  8.213.128.202      130  51.77.141.29       205  154.236.168.179     280 195.80.49.4

    56  8.213.128.214      131  51.81.32.81        206  154.236.177.101     281 195.80.49.5
    57  8.213.129.23       132  51.159.3.223       207  154.236.179.226     282 195.80.49.6
    58  8.213.129.36       133  51.178.182.23      208  157.100.26.69       283 195.80.49.7
    59  8.213.129.51       134  54.80.246.241      209  159.65.69.186       284 195.80.49.253
    60  8.213.129.57       135  61.9.48.169        210  159.65.133.175      285 195.80.49.254

    61  8.213.129.243      136  61.9.53.157        211  159.203.13.121      286 195.158.30.232
    62  8.214.41.50        137  62.75.219.49       212  160.16.242.164      287 197.149.247.82
    63  8.218.213.95       138  62.75.229.77       213  161.22.34.142       288 197.243.20.178
    64  09.200.156.102     139  62.78.84.159       214  164.132.137.241     289 198.46.200.70
    65  13.237.147.45      140  62.138.8.42        215  167.71.207.46       290 198.229.231.13

    66  20.47.108.204      141  62.204.35.69       216  167.86.81.208       291 212.112.113.178
    67  20.113.24.12       142  63.161.104.189     217  167.249.180.42      292 212.154.234.46
    68  23.19.7.136        143  66.29.154.103      218  168.205.100.36      293 212.174.44.87
    69  23.19.10.93        144  66.29.154.105      219  169.57.1.85         294 213.32.75.44
    70  23.81.127.253      145  69.163.252.140     220  170.81.35.26        295 213.230.69.193

    71  23.105.78.193      146  76.118.227.8       221  170.83.60.19        296 213.230.71.230
    72  23.105.78.252      147  77.83.86.65        222  170.155.5.235       297 213.230.90.106
    73  23.105.86.52       148  77.83.87.217       223  171.233.151.214     298 221.159.192.122
    74  23.108.42.228      149  77.104.97.3        224  172.241.156.1       299 222.158.197.138
    75  23.108.42.238      150  77.236.243.125     225  172.241.192.104     300 222.252.23.5
```

Answer (score 0):

previous examples were not able to return IP and CDIR without parts of the lines. This is what I use:

```
egrep -o '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}[\b|/{1,1}[0-9]{1,3}' file.txt
```

it matches lines:

```
    192.168.254.0/24#Comment
    22.198.172.141 # Comment
    othertext=21.35.142.193othertext
    othertext=21.35.142.0/24othertext
    19.38.57.0/24
    49.117.44.100   (tab)
    111.222.333.444(carriage)
    11.22.33.44.othertext
    18.68.53.99othertext=127.0.0.1 othertext 192.168.1.0/24othertext
```

following the regex provided from user Sarel Botha to add detection of valid  IPs, it would be:

```
grep -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[\b|/{1,1}[0-9]{1,3}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of them works try this: `strace -e connect -f -o save_it file_path`

**WARNING**: It runs the file with wine then get ip address so be careful! `save_it` just saves the result mentioned in the `file path`. `file_path` is points to an executable.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not given a specific file and you need to extract  IP address then we need to do it recursively.
grep command -> Searches a text or file for  matching a given string  and displays the matched string .

```
grep -roE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}'
```

`-r`        We can search the entire directory tree i.e. the current directory and all levels of sub-directories. It denotes recursive searching.

`-o`         Print only the matching string

`-E`        Use extended regular expression

If we would not have used the second grep command after the pipe we would have got the IP address along with the path where it is present

Comment: It is not necessary to pipe grep into grep.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat ip_address.txt | grep '^[0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[,].*$\|^.*[,][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[,].*$\|^.*[,][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}$'
```

Lets assume the file is comma delimited and the position of ip address in the beginning ,end and somewhere in the middle

First regexp looks for the exact match of ip address in the beginning of the line.
The second regexp after the or looks for ip address in the middle.we are matching it in such a way that the number that follows ,should be exactly 1 to 3 digits .falsy ips like 12345.12.34.1 can be excluded in this.

The third regexp looks for the ip address at the end of the line

Comment: `cat` is useless here. `grep` will accept a file as input as well as command output with redirection.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to get only IP addresses that began with "10", from any file in a directory:

```
grep -o -nr "[10]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}" /var/www
```

Answer (score -2):

for centos6.3

`ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr' | awk '{print $2}' | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $2}'`