# Find the IP address of the client in an SSH session

Tags: linux, ssh, network-programming, ip-address

I have a script that is to be run by a person that logs in to the server with [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

Is there a way to find out automatically what IP address the user is connecting from?

Of course, I could ask the user (it is a tool for programmers, so no problem with that), but it would be cooler if I just found out.

Comment: propose moving to serverfault, still great question though

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Check if there is an environment variable called:

```bash
$SSH_CLIENT
```

OR

```bash
$SSH_CONNECTION
```

(or any other environment variables) which gets set when the user logs in. Then process it using the user login script.

Extract the IP:

```bash
$ echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1}'
1.2.3.4
$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}'
1.2.3.4
```

Comment: @cwd i want to replace the ip in this command "iptables -A INPUT -s 93.203.118.251 -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j DROP" is that possible?

Comment: This was REMOTEHOST for me.

Comment: only works with non-sudoed users. e.g. if you have an ssh user and then escalate to root, a new shell is created and these variables are lost, unless you can trace back through the tree to find the original ssh pid and get the variables from /proc/$PID/environ

Comment: thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428109/extract-substring-in-bash this answer can be improved to simply `${SSH_CLIENT%% *}`

Comment: @Andrej look into `sudo -E`

Comment: Had to use echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $3}'

Comment: This is my go to for finding all env vars with a certain substring `env | grep SSH | sort`

Comment: Sometimes, it won't work if there was a network reconnection and IP address changed, but an actual SSH session stayed alive, for example. It may return a previous(old) IP address. Consider trying using `who` instead.

Answer (score 133):

You could use the command:

```
server:~# pinky
```

that will give to you somehting like this:

```
Login      Name                 TTY    Idle   When                 Where 

root       root                 pts/0         2009-06-15 13:41     192.168.1.133
```

Comment: That's awesome :-) Nerd humour ftw once again. According to `pinky --help`: `A lightweight 'finger' program; print user information. The utmp file will be /var/run/utmp.`

Comment: Why is it the my 'Where' in my output only shows the machine name and not the ip address?

Comment: Probably you got the nameserver configurated in your machine.

Comment: pinky will show _all_ logged in users, not just yourself

Answer (score 41):

Try the following to get just the IP address:

```bash
who am i|awk '{ print $5}'
```

Comment: pretty sure if you write whoami and you will get the name of the logged in user. there's no fifth thing or ip to print sorry. but whoami is a useful command

Comment: `who am i` != `whoami` on my Linux at least.  There is a fifth thing, and it is the host name of the client.

Comment: For anyone else wondering about `who am i`: The manpage for `who` says: `If ARG1 ARG2 given, -m presumed: 'am i' or 'mom likes' are usual.`. So really anything with two words works, also things like `who likes icecream`.

Comment: Building on this answer, I reduced it to `who -m --ips|awk '{print $5}'` so that I had only IP and no reverse-dns answer. Thanks for the help on `who am i`!

Comment: Some output may look like `admin    pts/0        Sep 30 13:20 1.1.1.1`, so this better be date-format-independent

Comment: Fails with tmux:  `who am i|awk '{ print $5}'` `(tmux(2445).%3)`

Answer (score 23):

Just type the following command on your Linux machine:

```
who
```

Answer (score 14):

```bash
who | cut -d"(" -f2 |cut -d")" -f1
```

Answer (score 6):

Improving on a prior answer. Gives ip address instead of hostname. --ips not available on OS X.

```bash
who am i --ips|awk '{print $5}' #ubuntu 14
```

more universal, change $5 to $6 for OS X 10.11:

```bash
WORKSTATION=`who -m|awk '{print $5}'|sed 's/[()]//g'`
WORKSTATION_IP=`dig +short $WORKSTATION`
if [[ -z "$WORKSTATION_IP" ]]; then WORKSTATION_IP="$WORKSTATION"; fi
echo $WORKSTATION_IP
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple command to get a list of recent users logged in to the machine is `last`. This is ordered most recent first, so `last | head -n 1` will show the last login. This may not be the currently logged in user though.

Sample output:

```
root     pts/0        192.168.243.99   Mon Jun  7 15:07   still logged in   
admin    pts/0        192.168.243.17   Mon Jun  7 15:06 - 15:07  (00:00)    
root     pts/0        192.168.243.99   Mon Jun  7 15:02 - 15:06  (00:03)    
root     pts/0        192.168.243.99   Mon Jun  7 15:01 - 15:02  (00:00)    
root     pts/0        192.168.243.99   Mon Jun  7 13:45 - 14:12  (00:27)    
root     pts/0        192.168.243.99   Mon May 31 11:20 - 12:35  (01:15)    
...
```

Answer (score 5):

```bash
who am i | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[()]//g' | cut -f1 -d "." | sed 's/-/./g'


export DISPLAY=`who am i | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[()]//g' | cut -f1 -d "." | sed 's/-/./g'`:0.0
```

I use this to determine my DISPLAY variable for the session when logging in via ssh and need to display remote X.

Comment: Useful one liner to add my IP to .htaccess files. Thank you.

I've made a modification for FreeBSD:
`who am i | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/[()]//g' | sed 's/\./\\./g'`

The last part escapes the dots.

Answer (score 4):

```bash
netstat -tapen | grep ssh | awk '{ print $4}'
```

Comment: doesn't work on CentOS 6.9 (net-tools 1.60 netstat 1.42) `(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=507 but you should be root.)`

Comment: @Jeff does `sudo ss -tapen | grep ssh | awk '{ print $4}'|grep -v ':22$'` work?

Comment: That doesn't quite work for me, had to use ```netstat -tapen | grep -F :22 | grep ESTABLISHED```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it in a programmatic way via an SSH library (https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute)

```java
public static String getIpAddress() throws TaskExecFailException{
    ConnBean cb = new ConnBean(host, username, password);
    SSHExec ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);
    ssh.connect();
    CustomTask sampleTask = new ExecCommand("echo \"${SSH_CLIENT%% *}\"");
    String Result = ssh.exec(sampleTask).sysout;
    ssh.disconnect();   
    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

an older thread with a lot of answers, but none are quite what i was looking for, so i'm contributing mine:

```bash
sshpid=$$
sshloop=0
while [ "$sshloop" = "0" ]; do
        if [ "$(strings /proc/${sshpid}/environ | grep ^SSH_CLIENT)" ];
then
                read sshClientIP sshClientSport sshClientDport <<< $(strings /proc/${sshpid}/environ | grep ^SSH_CLIENT | cut -d= -f2)
                sshloop=1
        else
                sshpid=$(cat /proc/${sshpid}/status | grep PPid | awk '{print $2}')
                [ "$sshpid" = "0" ] && sshClientIP="localhost" && sshloop=1
        fi
done
```

this method is compatible with direct ssh, sudoed users, and screen sessions. it will trail up through the process tree until it finds a pid with the SSH_CLIENT variable, then record its IP as $sshClientIP. if it gets too far up the tree, it will record the IP as 'localhost' and leave the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the following output from `who -m --ips` on Debian 10:

> root     pts/0        Dec  4 06:45 123.123.123.123

Looks like a new column was added, so `{print $5}` or "*take 5th column*" attempts don't work anymore.

Try this:

```bash
who -m --ips | egrep -o '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

Source:

- [@Yvan's comment on @AlexP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996231/find-the-ip-address-of-the-client-in-an-ssh-session#comment78322810_8568359)
- [@Sankalp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25573878)

Answer (score 1):

```bash
netstat -tapen | grep ssh | awk '{ print $10}'
```

Output:

two # in my experiment

```bash
netstat -tapen | grep ssh | awk '{ print $4}'
```

gives the IP address.

Output:

```bash
127.0.0.1:22 # in my experiment
```

But the results are mixed with other users and stuff. It needs more work.

Comment: my netstat only gives a truncated address for IPv6 and "127.0.0.1:22" is the server rather than the client, (which was specified in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming he opens an interactive session (that is, allocates a [pseudo terminal](http://linux.die.net/man/4/ptmx)) and you have access to stdin, you can [call an ioctl on that device](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tty) to get the device number (/dev/pts/4711) and try to find that one in [/var/run/utmp](http://linux.die.net/man/5/utmp) (where there will also be the username and the IP address the connection originated from).

Answer (score 0):

There could be a race condition, but this solution works as an ssh command. All the other solutions shown here require an ssh login.

$ ssh {host} last -1 | head -1 | awk '{print $3}'

Answer (score -1):

Usually there is a log entry in /var/log/messages (or similar, depending on your OS) which you could grep with the username.

Answer (score -1):

netstat will work (at the top something like this)
tcp        0      0 10.x.xx.xx:ssh          someipaddress.or.domainame:9379 ESTABLISHED

Comment: Thank you SO much for this answer, I ended up doing 'netstat | grep ssh'.

Comment: For security reasons this is bad because anybody could be connected to that port, not just you.

Answer (score -1):

Linux: who am i | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/[()]//g'

AIX: who am i | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/[()]//g'

Answer (score -1):

Search for SSH connections for "myusername" account;

Take first result string;

Take 5th column;

Split by ":" and return 1st part (port number don't needed, we want just IP):

netstat -tapen | grep "sshd: myusername" | head -n1 | awk '{split($5, a, ":"); print a[1]}'

---

Another way:

who am i | awk '{l = length($5) - 2; print substr($5, 2, l)}'

Comment: `sudo ss -tapen | grep "sshd: $(whoami)"|head -n1|awk '{split($5, a, ":"); print a[1]}'` says my ssh client is from `2a02` and your "Another way:" says `tmux(2445).%3`

Answer (score -1):

One thumb up for @Nikhil Katre's answer :

> Simplest command to get the last 10 users logged in to the machine is  `last|head`.
>
> To get all the users simply use `last` command

The one using `who` or `pinky` did what is basically asked. But But But they don't give historical sessions info.

Which might also be interesting if you want to know someone who has just logged in and
logged out already when you start this checking.

if it is a multiuser system. I recommand add the user account you are looking for:

```
last | grep $USER | head
```

EDIT:

In my case, both $SSH_CLIENT and $SSH_CONNECTION do not exist.