# How to distinguish displays in gnu-screen multi display mode?

Tags: gnu-screen

Let's attach to not-detached session few times:

In one terminal (say having pts 11):

```
$ screen -x    #say this will get pid 111
```

In another one (say pts 22):

```
$ screen -x    #get pid 222
```

Is there a way to **programatically** distinguish these two from inside of the screen?

OR (in another words)

Is there a way to link pid 111/222 or pty 11/22 to currently opened window inside?

Note I can tell "manually" by invoking screen command ":displays" (C-a *). But it seems that is not possible to redirect output of screen commands somewhere (to be clear: screen commands (C-a :), not commands in the screen).

Answer (score 0):

**`:displays` is a missing command within the possibilities offered by the `-Q` command-line option of screen**

Currently, you use the best existing option by typing manually `C-a *` to get the display list.

You could surely automatize this *outside of the screen* by using tools like `expect` to send keystrokes and `script` to log the session, but it would be a lot of work.

To do this *inside of the screen* (i.e. making bash log the user performing an action for instance), it's quite impossible unless you made some assumptions. See for instance [Access SSH client IP address, within a screen session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478810/access-ssh-client-ip-address-within-a-screen-session)