# Get local device IP from connected server

Tags: ssh, ip

I connected to my ubuntu server from my MacBook using SSH.

I want to know ip address of MacBook from the server.

How can I do that?

[edit] I would like to get ip using bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would comment this but I cant. We need more information. What language are you programming with. What have you tried.

Edit: Here is what you are looking for. This answer was taken from [Find the IP address of the client in an SSH session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996231/find-the-ip-address-of-the-client-in-an-ssh-session)

Please do a more through search for your problem before posting a question

Check if there is an environment variable called:

```
$SSH_CLIENT
```

OR

```
$SSH_CONNECTION
```

(or any other environment variables) which gets set when the user logs in. Then process it using the user login script.

Extract the IP:

```
$ echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{ print $1}'
1.2.3.4
$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}'
1.2.3.4
```

Comment: I edited. I want to get this from command line. server os is ubuntu

Comment: Do you want the server to send you back the IP address of the client or do you want to know the address of the server?

Comment: I want former. Want to get IP of client on server.