# Extract IP addresses & CIDR from text using regex in a linux shell

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, command-line

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427979/how-do-you-extract-ip-addresses-from-files-using-a-regex-in-a-linux-shell), I need to parse a text file for IP addresses and CIDR, so 0.0.0.0/24 or similar. How can this be done, preferably with grep?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `egrep` and a regular expression:

```
egrep '[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){0,3}/[0-9]+' /path/to/file
```

This will match all forms of IP/CIDR:

```
10/8
100.10/16
192.168.1/24
199.199.199.199/32
```

Although it will also match incorrect CIDR values, so such:

```
10/23482347234
```

Comment: grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\/[0-9]\{1,\}' file

^ also works!