# Masscan output How can i grab just the ip's and save to a file?

Tags: grep

After masscan scanning ip ranges it outputs ip's in such awfull format. Can somebody help me changing the output format or change it using grep or awk command?

```
open tcp 3389 77.239.225.198 1485353988
open tcp 3389 85.202.4.94 1485353988
open tcp 3389 217.14.53.187 1485353988
open tcp 3389 85.26.253.50 1485353988
open tcp 3389 87.238.96.58 1485353988
open tcp 3389 91.218.45.9 1485353988
open tcp 3389 178.46.167.147 1485353988
```

And i want it look like

```
77.239.225.19
85.202.4.94
217.14.53.187
85.26.253.50
87.238.96.58
91.218.45.9
178.46.167.147
```

Comment: awk is ok. Should the command that producec ip be inside <> ? And thanks alot for your help!

Comment: It could be useful for others if you provide your script/source. It also guarantees a more accurate answer to your problem

Comment: I have solved my problem a little bit changing the Inians code, problem is solved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you extract IP addresses from files using a regex in a linux shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427979/how-do-you-extract-ip-addresses-from-files-using-a-regex-in-a-linux-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Awk` as

```
masscan -iL ipp.txt --open --rate 60000 -p3389 | awk '{print $4}'
```

write it a new file using the re-direct operator,

```
masscan -iL ipp.txt --open --rate 60000 -p3389 | awk '{print $4}' > ipList.txt
```

Comment: Thanks alot! But how make awk save the result into new txt file?

Comment: I use a comand masscan -iL ipp.txt -oL ip.txt --open --rate 60000 -p3389

Comment: This command prints the results inti ip.txt Should i delete -oL ip.txt to use it with awk like: masscan -iL ipp.txt --open --rate 60000 -p3389 | awk '{print $4}' > ipList.txt

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @НикитаЛанфеуст: Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

In this way you do not save anything and do everything on the fly.

```
masscan -p<port> <subnet> --rate=600 --open-only --wait 0 2>&1 | grep ^Discovered | awk '{print $6}'
```