# Regular expression to extract ip between brackets

Tags: regex, awk, grep

My text format is

```
synchronised to server (192.168.204.1) at stratum 5
```

I want to extract the ip address in between the bracket and the text before it .like

```
synchronised to server (192.168.204.1)
```

what is the regular expression .(using awk or grep )

Comment: for given sample `grep -o '.*)'` would work.. if that doesn't solve your real use case,  change your sample... also, you are expected to show what you have tried yourself to solve this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean could help you with learning regex, but note that regex syntax/feature differs from tool to tool.. see documentation of respective tools for details

Comment: This looks trivial, but it works: awk -F'at' ' {print $1} ' Input_File

Comment: Try `sed 's/\(([^)]*)\).*/\1/' <<< str`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you extract IP addresses from files using a regex in a linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427979/how-do-you-extract-ip-addresses-from-files-using-a-regex-in-a-linux-shell)

Answer (score 0):

If your actual Input_file is same as shown samples then following may help you here.

```
awk 'match($0,/.*\([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\)/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using `sed` to do that? Here's the command you may tried

```
sed -r 's#(.*\([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}\)).*#\1#' Input_File
```

Brief explanation,

1. The regex `.*\([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}\)` would match anything ahead to **(IP address)**. Noted that the inner
   brackets shall be escaped.
2. `\1` would only print the matched part embraced by the outer brackets.

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
.*\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b\)
```

Breakdown :

`.*` selects all of the text before the IP address

`\b` matches a word boundary between a word character and a non-word character.

`([0-9]{1,3}\.)` matches numbers 0-9 a total of 1-3 times (to make 1.1.1.1 and 127.0.0.1 a valid IP address) and then matches a period.
`{3}` matches 3 times the token above.
`[0-9]{1,3}` matches numbers 0-9 a total of 1-3 times.
`\b` is a word boundary
`\)` matches parenthesis

Comment: Please add explanation.

Comment: done! Also why do StackOverflow answers get so many downvotes if the solution works?

Comment: Because the point is the *quality of the answer* and not just to drop in a solution. :) Take the time to write an answer, add explanation, add reference links if possible, and you'll get positive scores. I advise you to surf a bit and check answers with high votes. Take my upvote as a motivation. :)