# How can I save an ipv4 address and then use it for a query API?

Tags: python, shell

Here's the problem. I'm reading from my server (centos) visit log and use Sarel Botha's ipv4 address extract grep command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427979/how-do-you-extract-ip-addresses-from-files-using-a-regex-in-a-linux-shell).

As my server is running a java in nohup to serve connection, and all client's ipv4 address is written in nohup.out.

Combined, if I run

```
tail -f nohup.out|grep -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)'
```

then I would have a list of ip address following new record on nohup.out, like

```
111.111.111.111
222.222.222.222
```

and each ipv4 address would be output in a single line.

Now, I need to fetch each ipv4 address 'greped' from nohup.out and send it to a n ip geolocation query API, the formats required for query are

```
GET http://example.com/api/json/111.111.111.111
```

or

```
curl http://example.com/api/json/111.111.111.111
```

can any one tell me how can I save the ipv4 address, then use it for query, and have the query output following my tail -f command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe your grepped output to a curl command like this:

```
tail -f nohup.out | grep --line-buffered -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' | while read EVERY_IP
do
    curl "http://example.com/api/json/${EVERY_IP}";
done
```

NOTE: do not forget to add `--line-buffered` option to `grep` command

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print "URL"$0}'
```

You can get string like   URL+ip
but I do not know how to query use shell.

You can see this question:
[How to implement a pythonic equivalent of tail -F?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703640/how-to-implement-a-pythonic-equivalent-of-tail-f)