# How to use grep in way, where I can only get the word I want from a textfile?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, centos

I am trying to grep /var/log/secure to find the unique IP addresses that tried to use my instance. Every time, I try to grep I get the lines where the IP is located. How can I grep in a way where I just get the IP I want and store it in a text file. I'll post examples to clarify what I am looking for.

```
This is a sample /var/log/secure file:

Oct  9 22:45:48 ip-172-26-14-23 sshd[18080]: Disconnected from 34.101.251.82 port 59344 [preauth]
Oct  9 22:46:41 ip-172-26-14-23 sshd[18082]: Did not receive identification string from 209.17.97.18 port 64550
Oct  9 22:47:23 ip-172-26-14-23 sshd[18083]: Connection closed by 74.120.14.52 port 44578 [preauth]
Oct  9 22:54:03 ip-172-26-14-23 sshd[18088]: Invalid user cisco from 106.13.233.5 port 44180
Oct  9 22:54:03 ip-172-26-14-23 sshd[18088]: input_userauth_request: invalid user cisco [preauth]
Oct  9 22:54:03 ip-172-26-14-23 sshd[18088]: Received disconnect from 106.13.233.5 port 44180:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Oct  9 22:54:03 ip-172-26-14-23 sshd[18088]: Disconnected from 106.13.233.5 port 44180 [preauth]
Oct  9 22:56:53 ip-172-26-14-23 sshd[18090]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for reaia.tumblles.com [141.98.9.32] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Oct  9 22:56:54 ip-172-26-14-23 sshd[18090]: Connection closed by 141.98.9.32 port 34537 [preauth]
Oct  9 22:56:57 ip-172-26-14-23 sshd[18092]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for kei.tumblles.com [141.98.9.33] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
```

So what I want is to grep var/log/secure and just print the unique ips that tried to use my instance in a textfile like this:

```
**Desired output:**
34.101.251.82
74.120.14.52
106.13.233.5
141.98.9.32
So on....
I might have missed some but you get the idea.
```

when I try to grep the file with the command:  `sudo grep 'from' /var/log/secure | awk {print $2} > ips.out.` I get the following output to the file.

```
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
so on....
```

**9 is the date**
The ideology behind the input is that the word "from" is next to the ip address. So grep should go there and print the word next it with awk{print $2}.

However, I want to extract all IPS from anywhere in the file, not just the IPS after "from". What I did above is the only way I could do it at the moment. I was thinking to run multiple commands and make a bash script that gets Ips from all locations.

PS: I only want IPs after from!

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: please update the question to show a sample of the (complete) lines from `/var/log/secure` (would suggest a few lines you expect to match and a few lines that won't match), and then provide the expected output (corresponding to said sample lines)

Comment: ok I understand

Comment: why doesn't `209.17.97.18` show up in your expected output (it's prefaced with the string `'from'`)? why is `141.98.9.32` in the expected output since the line it resides on does not include the string `'from'`?  please update your expected output to correspond with the sample lines you've posted

Comment: It should I just forgot to include it.

Comment: See: [How do you extract IP addresses from files using a regex in a linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427979/3776858)

Comment: I have assumed you want only the IPs after `from `, not in brackets or any other IPs appearing in your logs, based on your description, if this is not enough, update with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using positive look behind with `grep`, you have to use `-P` for Perl-compatible regular expressions, also `-o` prints only the matched string.

```sh
> grep -Po "(?<=from )[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}" file
34.101.251.82 
209.17.97.18 
106.13.233.5 
106.13.233.5 
106.13.233.5
```

The initial part inside parentheses, the "`from` ", will be first matched, but ignored for the `-o` option, only the part after that will be considered.

This part is a simple expression to match an IP, meaning:

```
[0-9]{1,3}     (\.       [0-9]{1,3}) {3}
1-3 digits and (dot with 1-3 digits) {3 times more}
```

that's 4 numbers with maximum 3 digits, separated by dots.

See more about matching an IP into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/427979/3776858)

Comment: can you explain me [0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}"

Comment: I have updated the answer with some more explanations, I hope it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on shown samples only, could you please try following, written and tested in following link
https://ideone.com/bQGspU

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="from[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+port"
}
$2~/^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}$/{
  print $2
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

with GNU `awk` multi-char RS

`awk -v RS="[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}" 'RT{print RT}' file`

```
34.101.251.82
209.17.97.18
74.120.14.52
106.13.233.5
106.13.233.5
106.13.233.5
141.98.9.32
141.98.9.32
141.98.9.33
141.98.9.33
```

and the `uniq` command removes the adjacent duplicate lines

```
$ awk -v RS="[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}" 'RT{print RT}' file | uniq
34.101.251.82
209.17.97.18
74.120.14.52
106.13.233.5
141.98.9.32
141.98.9.33
```