# Locate text files with IP Address

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have used the ip address cmd.
After pulling up my ip address and trying to use find or grep I get nothing when searching for text files that include the ip address.

Following have been attempted as I was told would be proper, please help me correct.
Will use _ in place of ip address.
`

```
grep ___.___._.___
grep ^___.___._.___
```

When this failed I tried the find cmd and would get the error when trying to search all files under the directory.
find: unknown predicate `-rl`

I tried find another cmd and all I get is permission denied.

```
find / -type f -exec grep -l IP {} \;
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hope you're not concerned about IPv6 addresses, as those do have a habit of appearing when you least expect them.

Answer (score 1):

you can grep an IP address via command found at the answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/427989/13314263

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' file.txt
```

regarding you `find` command. root (`/`) is protected, so on a well configured system a normal user cannot view the contents of arbitrary files under it. try this instead:

```
sudo find / -type f -exec grep -l IP {} ;
```

Note the `sudo` in front. Alternatively `su` to root before executing your find: `su -`. And to combine it all for completeness:

```
sudo find / -type f -exec grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' {} \;
```